# ECS Fargate Services in AWS VPC - Unable to talk to each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

My architecture goes like

`Route53 -> SG -> ALB -> Target Group (IP) -> Task.`

In Route 53, I have namespaces defined. One is public and one is private.

```
domain.io   ----   Private
domain.io   ----   Public
```

I have two services, A and B.

ALBs look like:

```
<DNS of public LB attached to service A> = A-ALB
<DNS of public LB attached to service B> = B-ALB
```

In Private namespace, the entries look like:

```
service-a.domain.io - Type A record - A-ALB
service-b.domain.io - Type A record - B-ALB
```

In Public namespace, the entries look like:

```
service-a.domain.io - Type A record - A-ALB
service-b.domain.io - Type A record - B-ALB
```

A-ALB and B-ALB have a security group attached to them. This security group contains the VPC CIDR Block to allow all the incoming traffic from the VPC to pass through.

```
All traffic ---- All  ----  All ---  10.0.0.0/16
```

Tasks:

```
Task        Private IP        Public IP        
A           10.0.0.1          3.0.0.1
B           10.0.0.2          3.0.0.2
```

When service A calls service B, on the URL, service-b.domain.io, it picks up the value from the Private namespace and tries to access the task, via target group. But since the load balancer is listed there, service A tries to access service B using service A’s Public IP. And public IP of Service A (3.0.0.1) is not listed in the security group, it times out giving us no response. But when I whitelist this IP, then service A can access service B without any problems.

Since the load balancer is a public load balancer, therefore it resolves the public IP address of the task. Service B allows me to attach only one load balancer either a private or a public one So because this service also needs to be accessed publicly, then I definitely need to choose a public Load balancer.

I don’t mind adding IP to the security group, but every time I redeploy my service, and since its a fargate service, the public and private IPs of the task change, and I need to add new public IP to the security group.

How should service A access service B so that no security group changes are required? Should I make changes to the Route 53? ALBs? TG? Or Service?

Comment: I think the ideal solution would be to consider using service discovery [1] if your architecture allows.
[1] - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html

Comment: I tried using service discovery, but since I have a port associated to my application, it creates an SRV record in route 53 and DNS cannot resolve that.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that in most cases your service should be private with a load balancer.  If your service is public then someone could theoretically hit it directly and if you have HTTPS terminated at the ALB they can get around that.  Just give the ALB public subnets in the same VPC as the service but give service private subnets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have a Public ALB which is not supposed to be public as public load balancers usually have a 0.0.0.0/0 rule in security group and so will avoid the issue you are facing.

I would suggest you to create an internal load balancer instead of a public load balancer.

This way, when DNS Resolution of ALB DNS will happen, ALB's private IP will be returned and therefore the communication will happen internally, you can specify the security group id (as source) in Security group.

Comment: I thought of this, but what if I want the application to be accessed both internally and externally?